How to remove this hidden padding in Row in Jetpack Compose?
I have the following code:
@Composable
@Preview
fun ZoomButtons(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = {  },
            modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp).background(Color.White),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = 9999.dp,
                topEnd = 0.dp,
                bottomStart = 9999.dp,
                bottomEnd = 0.dp
            ),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color(0xFF5C5C5C)),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.zoom_minus),
                modifier = Modifier.size(14.dp),
                contentDescription = "Zoom out",
                tint = Color(0xFF0A8213)
            )
        }
        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = {  },
            modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp).background(Color.White),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = 0.dp,
                topEnd = 0.dp,
                bottomStart = 0.dp,
                bottomEnd = 0.dp
            ),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color(0xFF5C5C5C)),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.zoom_orig),
                modifier = Modifier.size(14.dp),
                contentDescription = "Zoom in",
                tint = Color(0xFF0A8213)
            )
        }
        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = {  },
            modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp).background(Color.White),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = 0.dp,
                topEnd = 9999.dp,
                bottomStart = 0.dp,
                bottomEnd = 9999.dp
            ),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color(0xFF5C5C5C)),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.zoom_plus),
                modifier = Modifier.size(14.dp),
                contentDescription = "Zoom in",
                tint = Color(0xFF0A8213)
            )
        }
    }
}

This produces:

How to remove the white space in first and second subbuttons?

To me that just looks like a problem with your border, it ends before it connect to next button in line.

The background Modifier is interfering with the internal implementations of the OutlinedButton Composable. Please try to remove
.background(Color.White)

and instead use
OutlinedButton(
    //...
    colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(containerColor = Color.White),
    //...
) {
    //...
}

Alternative:
You can consider to use the default SegmentedButton instead, which was released in October 2024 in 1.4.0-alpha01:
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.4.0-alpha01")

You can use it as follows:
@Composable
fun SegmentedButtonExample() {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val icons =
        listOf(
            Icons.Filled.ZoomOut,
            Icons.Filled.Refresh,
            Icons.Filled.ZoomIn
        )
    MultiChoiceSegmentedButtonRow {
        icons.forEachIndexed { index, icon ->
            SegmentedButton(
                shape = SegmentedButtonDefaults.itemShape(index = index, count = icons.size),
                icon = {},
                onCheckedChange = {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Button $index was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                },
                checked = false
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = icon,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(SegmentedButtonDefaults.IconSize)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:


Perfect! Thank you for the detailed answer.

Hidden padding is there in Outlined Button that too because you have kept Outlined Button size 32.dp which is smaller than it's usual size. To fix your issue try below code where i added padding(0.dp) to modifier of each button. It worked for me.


 @Composable
@Preview
fun ZoomButtons(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = {  },
            modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp).background(Color.White).padding(0.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = 9999.dp,
                topEnd = 0.dp,
                bottomStart = 9999.dp,
                bottomEnd = 0.dp
            ),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color(0xFF5C5C5C)),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.zoom_minus),
                modifier = Modifier.size(14.dp),
                contentDescription = "Zoom out",
                tint = Color(0xFF0A8213)
            )
        }
        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = {  },
            modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp).background(Color.White).padding(0.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = 0.dp,
                topEnd = 0.dp,
                bottomStart = 0.dp,
                bottomEnd = 0.dp
            ),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color(0xFF5C5C5C)),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.zoom_orig),
                modifier = Modifier.size(14.dp),
                contentDescription = "Zoom in",
                tint = Color(0xFF0A8213)
            )
        }
        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = {  },
            modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp).background(Color.White).padding(0.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = 0.dp,
                topEnd = 9999.dp,
                bottomStart = 0.dp,
                bottomEnd = 9999.dp
            ),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color(0xFF5C5C5C)),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.zoom_plus),
                modifier = Modifier.size(14.dp),
                contentDescription = "Zoom in",
                tint = Color(0xFF0A8213)
            )
        }
    }
}



